# QField app with live PostGIS connection photos won't synchronize

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qfield, cloud-gis

I am trialing QField and qfield cloud with organization plan. I have managed to setup live connection between QField and my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. My problem is that even if I have a photo type field (set in QGIS), I cannot receive the photos to my local computer.

I guess it fails at the really beginning. I can modify the record and take a photo in the app, I also can save it, and view it for a while in the saved record.

However I am not sure where that photos being saved temporary/permanently (in the QField folder, I cannot see anything) and when I push sync, the app says there is nothing to be synced.

Obviously the modified data does not have to be synced as the changes happen immediately due to the live connection, but I expect the photos should be synchronized. I am using IOS.

Comment: pictures/photo/attachments should be going to the DCIM folder https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures/#gallery-6

Comment: this is already set, unfortunately no pictures coming trough when the layer is a postgis (direct access) layer. Somehow the qfield app does not recognize the modified object to synchronize. So the sync button is inactive I cannot push changes. The modified attributes will be inserted to the postgis table, because of the live access, but how the pictures are coming trough if the app says there is nothing to be synchronized?